# How can I connect my function to a template in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

This is my dataTableController.php:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use DataTables\DataTablesInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/users", name="users_")
 */

class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  /**
  * @Route("", name="list")
  *
  * @param Request $request
  * @param DataTablesInterface $datatables
  * @return JsonResponse
  */

  const ID = 'users';

  public function usersAction(Request $request, DataTablesInterface $datatables): JsonResponse
  {
    try {
      // Tell the DataTables service to process the request,
      // specifying ID of the required handler.
      $results = $datatables->handle($request, 'users');

      return $this->json($results);

    }
    catch (HttpException $e) {
      // In fact the line below returns 400 HTTP status code.
      // The message contains the error description.
      return $this->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
  }

}
```

I want to connect the output to my homepage template.

So I changed this line..

```
return $this->json($results);
```

..to this line:

```
return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', json($results));
```

Is this correct?

Comment: why not try and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line should be working, you can retreive the information in your twig file by doing `{{json.something}}`:

```
return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', ['json' => json_encode($results)]);
```

Small edit: you don't have to parse the `$results` as json to your twig view. Twig can read the `$results` themselves without parsing it to json.

Comment: Can't find a json function in the standard lib ... whats that?

Comment: @JimPanse need to use json_encode for serversie datatables